# One Gradle Thymeleaf project reloads on resource change, the other relaunches

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, thymeleaf

EDIT: I've narrowed down the behavior a bit, not sure if there's a way to accomplish what I need.

Turns out, my app has the Thymeleaf templates one level down in the source tree:

```
src/main/resources/tools-server/templates
```

And I set this in my `tools-server.yml` file that gets explicitly loaded at application launch. Removing that specification from my configuration, and moving the `templates` directory up one level to

```
src/main/resources/templates
```

Allows `spring-boot-devtools` to simply reload the template without restarting the app. I think I’ll file a bug with the project, unless there’s a way around it.

---

I'm still getting the hang of Spring Boot, so bear with me. I've created two projects over the last few months, each starting from different examples found online.

With respect to reloading Thymeleaf templates, the first project does it neatly when they change, issuing two log messages when a template changes, and nothing more. The other does a complete stop and restart of the application, which causes problems because it re-creates the temporary security password, among other things (it also takes longer).

The two `gradle.build` files are nearly identical, with slightly different dependencies. I'm not sure if those are the differences causing the different behavior.

The working one:

```
buildscript
{
    ext
    {
        springBootVersion = "1.4.3.RELEASE"
    }
    repositories
    {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies
    {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath group: "com.layer", name: "gradle-git-repo-plugin", version: "2.0.2"
    }
}

apply plugin: "git-repo"
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: "spring-boot"

jar
{
    baseName = "HOA"
    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories
{
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty/" }
    maven { url "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies
{
    compile group: "org.mindrot",                   name: "jbcrypt",                    version: "0.4-atlassian-1"
    compile group: "org.eclipse.persistence",       name: "javax.persistence",          version: "2.1.1"
    compile group: "org.springframework.data",      name: "spring-data-jpa",            version: "1.10.4.RELEASE"
    compile group: "org.springframework.hateoas",   name: "spring-hateoas",             version: "0.21.0.RELEASE"

    compile group: "com.h2database",                name: "h2",                         version: "1.4.192"

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-groovy-templates")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    //  Automated Testing

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc")
}

dependencyManagement
{
    imports
    {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR1"
    }
}


compileJava
{
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:all" << "-Xdiags:verbose"
}

bootRepackage
{
    mainClass = "com.latencyzero.hoa.Application"
}

bootRun
{
    addResources = true
}
```

The messy one:

```
buildscript
{
    ext
    {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.3.RELEASE'
    }

    repositories
    {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies
    {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

archivesBaseName = 'toolcrib'

compileJava
{
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:all" << "-Xdiags:verbose"
}

jar
{
    manifest
    {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'ToolCrib',
                    'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories
{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement
{
    imports
    {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR3'
    }
}

dependencies
{
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')

    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

springBoot
{
    mainClass = "com.latencyzero.toolcrib.services.tools.ToolsServer"
}


bootRun
{
    addResources = true
}
```

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

Have you had [a look to the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-restart-exclude)

> By default changing resources in /META-INF/maven, /META-INF/resources, /resources, /static, /public or /templates will not trigger a restart but will trigger a live reload.

And

> If you want to customize these exclusions you can use the spring.devtools.restart.exclude

There is also `spring.devtools.restart.additional-exclude` to add more excludes and keep the defaults. In your case, you should add the following to your configuration:

```
spring.devtools.restart.additional-exclude=classpath:/tools-server/templates/
```

Comment: That section did not seem relevant as I was skimming through the code to find an answer. I didn't want to exclude my files from triggering reload. Also, it comes right after an introduction to class reloading, which, aside from not being about templates (i.e. not code that's loaded by the class loader), implies it's for built things (in the `build` directory). I wanted it to look in my source directory for files, which it does if they're in the right place, but it seems magical and unexplained how and when it chooses to do that.

Comment: If I exclude `classpath:/...`, will it still look for changes in the original source locations, or will it only see them if a build of some kind copies those files to the build location?

Comment: "I didn't want to exclude my files from triggering reload"  The property is called "restart.exclude". I don't know what else to say, this is exactly what you're asking. If the doc is confusing, tell us how and we will adapt.

Comment: You are mentioning a feature that doesn't exist in the first place. If you put your template in the default location, you also have to update the classpath for a reload (!= restart) to take effect. I've created [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7886) to review the documentation.

Comment: I'm watching it work right now. I can edit files in my `src/main/resources/templates` directory (note, *not* in `build/resources/main/templates`), and Spring picks up the change and reloads the template almost immediately. This allows me to edit templates without worrying about copying them back from `build` to `src` before checkin, an excellent feature. It would be nice if it did this regardless of where under `src` the files live, only that they're template files.

Comment: There are a few ways to make this work but this conversation is going in circles. There is nothing different in devtools regarding the location of the template as long as you do what I've told you in my answer. If you want more details, let's switch to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132413/discussion-between-stephane-nicoll-and-rick).